# Identifying pixels with sun glint in a satellite image (for atmospheric correction)

Tags: envi, atmospheric-correction, pixel

Wondering if anyone knows a way (perhaps objective) to identify pixels that are infected with sun glint in an image. I'm using Hedley's 2005 approach in a python to deglint my image but this approach requires selecting pixels over deep waters with glint/specular reflection. I'm having trouble identifying this visually in ENVI - even using different contrast options.

Comment: One possible approach is to use Mahalanobis distance as described in [this paper](https://www.cis.rit.edu/~cnspci/references/vanaardt2011.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

@user18058 I have thought that you solved your problem about the sun-glint removal. I using Lyzenga algorithm to correct sun-glint in RGBNir images taken using DMC Camera and the results were impressive. If you need help with sun-glint, let me know. Maybe I could help you solve this issue. The first image(left) presents the raw image containing sun-glint. The second image show the glint removal applying the Lyzenga Algorithm for all image and the last image (right) show the results from Lyzenga Algorithm only for the water.

To execute the algorithm only for the water I used a mask based on a NDWI values. It was interesting because the values from pixels out the water were preserving.

[image]

Comment: de Paula, Yes please, I am still interested. Thanks

Comment: @user18058 Please write an email: cesardepaula@usp.br

Comment: @CésardePaula could you please help me in this question. It seems similar but it is UAS imagery https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354640/best-way-to-correct-uas-imagery-sun-glint-over-a-water-surface