# Sun glints and landsat 8 surface reflectance product

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat-8, atmospheric-correction

I was wondering if the Landsat 8 surface reflectance product needs to be corrected for sun glints if I want to use it for atmospheric correction over water surfaces.

---

I'm actually working on satellited derived bathymetry and I'm using Hedley's 2009 approach for sun glint correction. Just wanted to be sure I still have to deglint Landsat SR products.

Comment: Two papers that may be useful: 1) Jagalingam, P., Akshaya, B. J., & Hegde, A. V. (2015). Bathymetry Mapping Using Landsat 8 Satellite Imagery. Procedia Engineering, 116, 560-566. and 2)  Kay, S., Hedley, J. D., & Lavender, S. (2009). Sun glint correction of high and low spatial resolution images of aquatic scenes: A review of methods for visible and near-infrared wavelengths. Remote Sensing, 1(4), 697-730.

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/229499/8104

Answer (score 5):

The Landsat 8 Surface Reflectance products are not sunglint corrected , so if your application is going to be adversely impacted by the presence of sunglints, then you should implement a suitable deglinting method.
For more detail on the exact processing algorithms used for the Surface Reflectance Product, see https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat-surface-reflectance-high-level-data-products - you will note the fact that there is no mentioning of sunglints on that website. Deglinting would usually be perceived as a separate step in the processing chain, and as it is not mentioned in the description, it would appear safe to assume that no such method is applied.
As for which deglinting method to implement, that becomes very opinion based, as pretty much every major researcher in the fields of ocean colour / satellite derived bathymetry / benthic habitat mapping have suggested a methodology.